# inserting values from 2 mysql tables to single jtable row

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jtable

I'm new to java. currently trying to make a program which manipulates with data from mysql. I have several tables in mysql and I need to add data to a single jtable row from 2 mysql tables. Now I'm getting data in different rows. Below my code for one table. Any suggestions how to change it?

```
public void fill_rs_table_test(){
DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();

model.setColumnIdentifiers(new String[] {"rs_name","rs_number","firm_id"});

try{
String sql = "select * from inf_rs";
theView.pst = theView.conn.prepareStatement(sql);
theView.rs = theView.pst.executeQuery();

while(theView.rs.next()){

String rs_name = theView.rs.getString ("rs_name");
String rs_number = theView.rs.getString ("rs_number");
String firm_id = theView.rs.getString ("firm_id");

model.addRow(new Object[] {rs_name, rs_number,firm_id}); 

}
}
catch (Exception e){
}

this.theView.rs_table.setModel(model);
for (int i = 0, x = 0; i < theView.rs_table.getColumnModel().getColumnCount(); i++)
this.theView.rs_table.getColumnModel().getColumn(i).setCellEditor(new javax.swing.table.TableCellEditor(){  

@Override
public boolean isCellEditable(java.util.EventObject anEvent) {
    return false; 
}
```

});

Comment: `Now I'm getting data in different rows.` Well, you only show one query and the data correctly is added to different row. If the data from the two tables belongs in a single row, then why don't you write the SQL to get the data from both tables in one query instead of creating two queries and attempting to merge it on the client side?

Comment: Solution is very simple, use `Vector` or `Object` array.

Comment: @KishanSarsechaGajjar it's doesn't matter, he has another problem with data aggregation. see the answer of camickr it's usefull

Comment: Almost forgot) Another issue. firm_id in inf_rs table is a foreign key. so data from 2 tables should be inserted in one row according to firm_id.